# To use JOIN or UNION

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am supporting a legacy application which has a `LINQ` code which goes like this:

```
query1 = (from s in DBContext.Table_A JOIN DBCOntext.Table_B ON A.ID=B.ID 
where a.SUPERVISOR = '9999' Select new ClassA {....}

query2 = (from s in DBContext.Table_A JOIN DBCOntext.Table_B ON A.ID=B/ID 
where a.APPROVER = '1111'  Select new ClassA {....}

query1.join(query2).ToList()
```

My question is can the above 2 queries be combined into 1 query using `JOIN`. Notice that the only difference between the 2 queries is the `WHERE` clause.
Will this result in any performance improvements?

A point to be noted that all the entities used here are Views.

Thanks
Parameswaran

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know for sure is to test as it's hard to know what optimizations LINQ might use.
In my personal opinion, combining them would be more efficient (unless LINQ does that as an optimization under the hood) because you'd only have to go through the table once (instead of twice).
Your where clause could be rewritten as:

```
where a.SUPERVISOR='9999' or a.APPROVER='1111'
```